# Javascript Dojo AJAX (XHR) Requests with Custom Headers in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a request using [dojo.xhrGet](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/xhrGet#example-8-dojo-xhrget-call-with-headers) to grab some XML data from a server.  I'm using dojo 1.4.0.

The server requires that I pass credentials through a custom HTTP header called `Myauthtoken`.

Everything works fine in Safari. The code pops up a dialog showing `[object Document]`.  But in Firefox, the dialog shows `null`.  Somewhere along the process, the custom header is being dropped or corrupted, and the server doesn't accept it.

The relevant code looks something like this:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
  url: 'https://host.com/path/to/thing?param1=one&param2=two',
  headers: {
    'Myauthtoken': 'username:password'
  },
  handleAs: 'xml',
  load: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    alert("error: " + e);
  }
});
```

In Firefox, Firebug displays the following Request Headers:

> **Host:** host.com
>   **User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7
>   **Accept:** text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   **Accept-Language:** en-us,en;q=0.5
>   **Accept-Encoding:** gzip,deflate
>   **Accept-Charset:** ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   **Keep-Alive:** 300
>   **Connection:** keep-alive
>   **Origin:** null
>   **Access-Control-Request-Method:** GET
>   **Access-Control-Request-Headers:** myauthtoken,x-requested-with

The server responds with a 403 (Forbidden) and these Response Headers:

> **Date:** Thu, 28 Jan 2010 20:02:47 GMT
>   **Server:** Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0.6
>   **Content-Type:** text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>   **Content-Length:** 337
>   **Connection:** close

---

**Update!**
I've been researching, and it looks like the problem is that Firefox is attempting to [preflight the request because of the custom headers](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/xhrGet#example-8-dojo-xhrget-call-with-headers), while Safari isn't, and is instead just sending the custom headers without first checking if they're valid.

I also figured out [how to look at the Request in Safari](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector):

> **Cache-Control:** max-age=0
>   **Content-Type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   **Myauthtoken:** username:password
>   **User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10

And the Response Headers:

> **Cache-Control:** no-store
>   **Connection:** close
>   **Content-Length:** 236391
>   **Content-Type:** application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
>   **Date:** Fri, 29 Jan 2010 23:02:22 GMT
>   **Server:** Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0.6

The main difference being the `Content-Length: 235391`

Unfortunately, I'm still not much closer to actually finding a solution- still looking for some good ideas, or really any ideas at all.

Any thoughts on what's going on and how I can get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more research, it looks like the problem is that the server is expecting the headers to be case-sensitive, while Firefox is converting the headers to lowercase.

Firefox is sending `myauthtoken`, while the server is expecting `Myauthtoken`.

In the end, it all came down to a bit of code where we were using [`getFirstValue(String name)`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.0/api/org/restlet/util/Series.html#getFirstValue%28java.lang.String%29), which defaults to case-sensitive, instead of [`getFirstValue(String name, boolean ignoreCase)`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.0/api/org/restlet/util/Series.html#getFirstValue%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Watch out for case-sensitive headers!

Answer (score 0):

For custom headers, I believe you need to use the `X-` prefix:

> > **X-Myauthtoken:** username:password

```
  headers: {
    'X-Myauthtoken': 'username:password'
  },
```

The server will need to accept it as well, since it's a non-standard header.

Comment: In what context do you need an `X-` prefix?  It works fine with Safari and curl.  Is this only in Firefox?  Do you know of any documentation?